# return Empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two classes in a different file, and I want to pass list values from one to another, but it gives me an empty list; my code is very long, so that I will provide an example.

Example: file1.py

```
class a:
   def __init__ (self):
     self.result = [] 
   def set_result(self, result_a):
      self.result.append(result_a)
```

file2.py

```
class b:
   def add_value_to_list():
     file1.a().set_result("add_value")
```

The code is to understand the idea. I want  `self.result` returned all values that I added by using  `add_value_to_list()`
I want `self.result = ["add_value"]` that I passed from  `add_value_to_list()`

Comment: pass `self` to `set_result(self, result_a)`

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: `file1.a()` creates a new instance of `a` each time, so the result is added to a different list each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two problems with this, the first was fixed with an edit, but the second may be more structural

- missing `self` arg to method
  methods normally need to be passed this as their first argument to access other methods and data attached to their instance of the class
- class `b` creates a new instance of `a` every time `add_value_to_list` is called (`a()`), instead it should probably create a single instance of `a` during its init and refer to it on some `self.`

Comment: you may be creating a new instance of `a` when you check its contents! however a clearer [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help us help you or may solve your problem during its creation!

Comment: I understand you and I solve the problem as you said Thanks.